# Preciso que uma função retorne true ou false, dependendo da quantidade de letras

Tags: java, android, regex

```
boolean b = mascara.matches("\\D{0,4}");
```

Preciso que uma máscara (como por exemplo `"GHO-1A23"`) seja verificada que contém somente 4 letras.

Se tiver 4 só digita número e se tiver menos que 4 deixa digitar mais uma letra.

Porém desse modo acima, ela retorna `false` quando o usuário vai digitar uma proxima letra já com a mascara sendo `"GHO-1"`.

Comment: Obrigado! Não estava conseguindo colocar como código

Comment: A [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) tem várias dicas para formatar o código. E `\\D{0,4}` verifica se a string contém **entre zero e 4 caracteres que não são dígitos**. Ou seja, se tiver 1 letra, serve. Se não tiver nenhuma, também serve. Mas se tiver um dígito, não serve. Ela não verifica se tem exatamente 4 letras. Outro detalhe é que `matches` verifica se a string inteira corresponde à expressão. Se a máscara for `GHO-1`, ela tem um dígito e por isso não corresponde à `\\D{0,4}` (entre zero e 4 caracteres que não são dígitos) - por isso retorna `false`

Comment: Segundo uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339688/validar-placas-com-o-novo-padr%C3%A3o-mercosul) realizado, por você ontem. Vc queria validar placas. Mas o código que vc estava criando era para inserir uma máscara de placa. Você precisa ser um pouco mais objetivo na pergunta, pois oq receber de resposta, pode não te atender. Só para tentar te ajudar um pouco, no mundo real, quando tiver placas do mercosul, ainda vai ter placas do modelo antigo LLL-NNNN (L - letra e N - número). Como o seu código vai atender as 2 possibilidades?

Comment: Resolvi o problema. A classe completa resolve as duas possibilidades.

Comment: Então crie uma resposta colocando o código. Pode ajudar futuros usuários que tenham a mesma dúvida que a sua.

Answer (score 2):

Então modifiquei a expressão do regex:

```
mascara.matches("\\D{0,4}|\\D{0,4}\\d{0,2}|\\D{0,4}\\d{0,3}");
```

Mo meu teste atendeu todos os casos, inclusive para as placas antigas, mas se alguém encontrar alguma divergência, ficarei grato em me avisar.

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class PlacaUtils {

    HomeActivity context;

    public static String unmask(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
                .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
                .replaceAll("[)]", "");
    }

    public static TextWatcher insert(final EditText ediTxt) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            String mask = "UUU-####";
            boolean isUpdating;
            String old = "";


            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                ediTxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
                String str = PlacaUtils.unmask(s.toString());
                String mascara = "";
                if (isUpdating) {
                    old = str;
                    isUpdating = false;
                    return;
                }
                int i = 0;
                for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                    if ((m != '#' && m != 'U') && str.length() > old.length()) {
                        mascara += m;
                        continue;
                    }
                    try {
                        Character c = str.charAt(i);
                        if (mascara.length() < 3) {
                            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                                mascara += str.charAt(i);
                            }
                        } else if (mascara.length() >= 3) {
                            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                                mascara += str.charAt(i);
                            } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                                boolean b = mascara.matches("\\D{0,4}|\\D{0,4}\\d{0,2}|\\D{0,4}\\d{0,3}");
                                if (b) {
                                    mascara += str.charAt(i);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                isUpdating = true;
                if (str.length() < 3) {
                    ediTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                } else if (str.length() >= 3) {
                    ediTxt.setInputType((InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT));
                }

                ediTxt.setText(mascara);
                ediTxt.setSelection(mascara.length());


            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        };
    }

    public static boolean isValid(final String placa) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(placa)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (placa.matches("[A-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2}")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String masked(String placa) {

        placa = unmask(placa);
        placa = placa.substring(0, 3) + "-" + placa.substring(3, 7);

        return placa;
    }
}
```

Comment: Se resolveu, lembre de marcar como aceita depois pra fechar o post

Comment: Aproveite e remova sua pergunta antiga, que era similar a esta, aí o site fica mais organizado e você recupera seus pontos.